# Image div that expands to display more info while the other div slides to the side

Tags: html, css

Here is a site that I want to create which is similar.  [www.outdatedbrowser.com](http://www.outdatedbrowser.com)  I will be using a framework similar to bootstrap for the layout.  It will be a a full width 4 column image side by side. When you hover on one image it expands to display more of the image and some content while the other images gets slightly narrower.  Here is an image  demonstrating what I mean. I would like to use only css3 but jquery will be ok also.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="zh-CN">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>accordions</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        li{
            list-style: none;
        }
        .accordion ul{
            width: 950px;
            font-size: 0;
        }
        .accordion ul li{
            width: 225px;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }

        .accordion ul:hover li{
            width: 200px;
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }
        .accordion ul li:hover{
            width: 300px;
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }
        .accordion ul li img{
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="accordion">
    <ul>
        <li class="image">
            <img src="image/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="pic"/>
        </li>
        <li class="image">
            <img src="image/example-slide-2.jpg" alt="pic"/>
        </li>
        <li class="image">
            <img src="image/example-slide-3.jpg" alt="pic"/>
        </li>
        <li class="image">
            <img src="image/example-slide-4.jpg" alt="pic"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

May be able to help you .